Unable to connect to an Oracle database with the JDBC thin driver
I'm unable to connect to an Oracle database with the JDBC thin driver. The same URL works with SQL*plus, but not with JDBC thin. I tried with Java 17 and the latest ojdbc JAR.
Below is the Java code that I tried
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL")) {

    System.out.println("Connection established");
    System.out.println("statement executed");

    while (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
}

Below are error logs.
2024-08-02T04:50:16.708-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
Connection establishment starts for URL--->jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<host_ip>)(PORT=8848))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>)))
2024-08-02T04:51:17.233-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : entering args (oracle.jdbc.internal.AbstractConnectionBuilder$1@61846e3a)
2024-08-02T04:51:17.234-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : traceId=4E397AFF.
2024-08-02T04:51:17.238-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : Session Attributes:
sdu=8192, tdu=2097152
nt: host=<host_ip>, port=8848, socketOptions={0=YES, 1=NO, 17=0, 18=false, 2=0, 20=true, 38=TLS, 23=40, 24=50, 40=false, 25=0}
    socket=null
client profile={oracle.net.encryption_types_client=(), oracle.net.crypto_seed=, oracle.net.authentication_services=(), oracle.net.setFIPSMode=false, oracle.net.kerberos5_mutual_authentication=false, oracle.net.encryption_client=ACCEPTED, oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=ACCEPTED, oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=()}
connection options=[host=<host_ip> port=8848 protocol=tcp service_name=<service_name> addr=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<host_ip>)(PORT=8848)) conn_data=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(PORT=8848)(HOST=<host_ip>))(CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=gms-prod-ha2)(USER=opc))(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>))) done=true]
onBreakReset=false, dataEOF=false, negotiatedOptions=0x841, connected=false
TTIINIT enabled=false, TTC cookie enabled=false

2024-08-02T04:51:17.238-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : traceId=4E397AFF, anoEnabled=true.
2024-08-02T04:51:17.239-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : Got Resend, SessionTraceId = 4E397AFF
2024-08-02T04:51:17.240-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : Connection established. Cleared conn strategy stack
2024-08-02T04:51:17.240-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : Sending break marker, SessionTraceId = 4E397AFF
2024-08-02T04:51:17.241-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : throwing

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-17002: I/O error: Connection reset, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17002/
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(T4CConnection.java:1660) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:1142) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1206) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:105) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:886) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:693) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681) ~[java.sql:na]
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229) ~[java.sql:na]
        at com.manh.gms.jdbc.JdbcService.connect(JdbcService.java:21) ~[!/:odbc-latest]
        at com.manh.gms.jdbc.JdbcController.establishJdbcConnection(JdbcController.java:29) ~[!/:odbc-latest]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(T4CConnection.java:1655) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.blockingRead(SocketChannelImpl.java:1293) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$1.read(SocketAdaptor.java:194) ~[na:na]
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.doBlockedRead(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:600) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:536) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:1224) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:272) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:205) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:148) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:121) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:111) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:930) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:464) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.receivePacket(T4C8TTIdty.java:926) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.doRPC(T4C8TTIdty.java:776) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.negotiateSession(T4CConnection.java:3522) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.negotiateTTC(T4CConnection.java:893) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:1078) ~[ojdbc11.jar!/:23.5.0.24.07]
        ... 58 common frames omitted

2024-08-02T04:51:17.248-04:00  INFO 7310 --- [jdbc-connectivity] [nio-5432-exec-1] oracle.jdbc                              : properties={LOCALE=en_US, DriverVersion=23.5.0.24.07, java.library.path: =/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib, java.class.path: =jdbc-odbc-latest.jar, java.version: =17.0.12}.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-17002: I/O error: Connection reset, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-17002/
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(T4CConnection.java:1660)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:1142)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:1206)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:105)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:886)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:693)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
        at com.manh.gms.jdbc.JdbcService.connect(JdbcService.java:21)
        at com.manh.gms.jdbc.JdbcController.establishJdbcConnection(JdbcController.java:29)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonIOException(T4CConnection.java:1655)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.blockingRead(SocketChannelImpl.java:1293)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$1.read(SocketAdaptor.java:194)
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.doBlockedRead(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:600)
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:536)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:1224)
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:272)
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:205)
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:148)
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:121)
        at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:111)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:930)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:464)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.receivePacket(T4C8TTIdty.java:926)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.doRPC(T4C8TTIdty.java:776)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.negotiateSession(T4CConnection.java:3522)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.negotiateTTC(T4CConnection.java:893)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:1078)
        ... 58 more

I tried with Java 17 and latest ojdbc11 JAR.

Most of the log you've included is noise to wade through. The ORA-17002 seems to be the important bit, but isn't one or Oracle's most helpful messages, even if you follow the link. Are SQL*Plus and your Java code running on the same machine - so connecting from the same source? You haven't said which database version you're connecting to - is that compatible with the latest (23ai) JDBC driver?

What is the database version that you are trying to connect? Also, you can use one of these samples DataSourceSample.java (https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/blob/main/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) or UCPSample.java(https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/blob/main/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/UCPSample.java) to check the connection.

I am seeing this same failure (sporadically - 9 out of 10 times). Fails after the "sending break marker" message. Then "throwing" and I get the SQLRecoverableException. But where OP sees "Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset", I see "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer".
I can connect using SQLDeveloper, no problem on the same port my program is trying.

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") has been discussed in the following thread. Iow, you don't need to call Class.forName

That's a true statement. I think the question is somewhat different, though. There must be something incorrect in the JDBC URL.
